# How to view Daedalus' Stake Pool Rankings, without having Daedalus downloaded?

Tags: stake-pool, daedalus

Is there a way to view Daedalus' stake pool rankings, without having Daedalus installed?

I had to uninstall Daedalus because my laptop ran out of room.  Note, other explorers like AdaPools and Eternl use their own ranking formula.

Answer (score 1):

Daedalus wallet uses SMASH server to fetch data about Stake Pools.

IOG SMASH server can be found here https://smash.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io/api/v1

Documentation about SMASH server, and interesting queries, [here](https://docs.cardano.org/cardano-components/smash)

However I think the sorting algorithm is up to Daedalus itself and hardcoded in the software, so no way known to me, to retrieve it.